# Inner Join kills query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 2 queries below that are identical except for the JOIN to mjnEmployeeDepartment.  The first query uses LEFT OUTER JOIN and the second uses INNER JOIN.  They both return the same data but the INNER JOIN takes 4.5 minutes to execute whereas the LEFT OUTER JOIN takes 4 seconds.  Can anyone suggest what might be happening here?

I am running the code in SMS 2017 against a SQL 2012 database.

```
Select
Count(*) --23878 00:00:00

From
       dbo.mjnEmployee as e
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeStatus as s
                     on e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeEmploymentInfo as RankNo
                     On e.EmployeeId = RankNo.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeOfficeAssociation as Office
                     On e.EmployeeId = Office.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeEmploymentInfo as TrackNo
                     On e.EmployeeId = TrackNo.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeUnit as Unit
                     on e.EmployeeID = Unit.EmployeeID
                     And Unit.Iteration = 1

              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeDepartment as Department
                     on e.EmployeeID = Department.EmployeeID

              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Supervisor
                     On  e.EmployeeId = Supervisor.ObjectEmployeeId
                     and Supervisor.EmployeeAssociationType = 2
              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Manager
                     On Manager.ObjectEmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
                     and Manager.EmployeeAssociationType = 1
              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Assistant
                     On  e.EmployeeId = Assistant.ObjectEmployeeId
                     and Assistant.EmployeeAssociationType = 3
              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Advisor
                     On e.EmployeeId = Advisor.ObjectEmployeeId
                     and Advisor.EmployeeAssociationType = 4

Select
Count(*) --23878 00:04:37

From
       dbo.mjnEmployee as e
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeStatus as s
                     on e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeEmploymentInfo as RankNo
                     On e.EmployeeId = RankNo.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeOfficeAssociation as Office
                     On e.EmployeeId = Office.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeEmploymentInfo as TrackNo
                     On e.EmployeeId = TrackNo.EmployeeID
              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeUnit as Unit
                     on e.EmployeeID = Unit.EmployeeID
                     And Unit.Iteration = 1

              Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeDepartment as Department
                     on e.EmployeeID = Department.EmployeeID

              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Supervisor
                     On  e.EmployeeId = Supervisor.ObjectEmployeeId
                     and Supervisor.EmployeeAssociationType = 2
              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Manager
                     On Manager.ObjectEmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
                     and Manager.EmployeeAssociationType = 1
              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Assistant
                     On  e.EmployeeId = Assistant.ObjectEmployeeId
                     and Assistant.EmployeeAssociationType = 3
              Left Outer Join dbo.mjnEmployeeAssociation as Advisor
                     On e.EmployeeId = Advisor.ObjectEmployeeId
                     and Advisor.EmployeeAssociationType = 4
```

Comment: My first thought is a lack of indexes.

Comment: Me too Duffy but wouldn't a missing index effect a left join as well as an inner join?  Also, when I look at the execution plans SMS does not suggest any new index.

Comment: At a very minimum you should [include the actual Execution Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/1260204), you could use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and share the link in your question. Also [try to read it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759097/1260204), maybe you can figure out the performance issue(s) with your query.  Finally include the [schema DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) along with the query you are executing.

Comment: Look into indexing, and look into re-ordering the joins, if possible.  Sometimes just addressing those two things will correct slowness.

Comment: I don't know what you look for in the execution plan to spot when an index is needed.  If I were looking at a MySQL or SQL Server database I'd look for TABLE SCAN.

Comment: I will try to post the execution plans.  They are rather lengthy.  In SMS when you look at the execution plan there will be a suggestion to add an index if the optimizer thinks you need one.

Comment: Are the statistics up to date?

Comment: How do I know if the Statistics are up to date?

Comment: Look in the catalog-tables or simply use UPDATE STATISTICS on all tables to be sure

Comment: Fast Plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1LX1gwsZ
 
Slow Plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJl0elwj-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to look at the difference between an inner and outer join. In essence an inner join will give the rows that are common to both tables where an outer join will give all rows in table A and any rows in table B that match.

This likely explains why your inner join is faster (although it's difficult to say without knowing the data).

The differences are illustrated really well in another question here:

[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: The INNER JOIN is the slow one.  That's why I am confused.  They both return the same data but itakes the inner join almost 100 times longer to do it.

Comment: Your question states They both return the same data but the INNER JOIN takes 4 minutes to execute whereas the LEFT OUTER JOIN takes 4.5 minutes hence my answer

Comment: BAH!  I meant to type 4 SECONDS.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the, below table used in the join missing on clause which leads to multiply all rows with the earlier set of results,

```
Inner Join dbo.mjnEmployeeDepartment as Department
                     on e.EmployeeID = Department.EmployeeID
```

Is there any other table having this column ? If yes then that needs to be used.

Comment: The rows aren't being duplicated.  Both versions of the query return the exact same data.

Comment: its not abt the same data, in first query its left outer join and in second query its inner join on this table

Comment: It is the same data.  In this case, the data in both tables is a 1-1 exact match so the left join versus the inner join returns the same exact data set. The difference is in the execution plan selected by the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using a combination of reordering the tables and using `FORCESEEK` optimizer hint.  We moved the conditional join table to be after all the inner join tables and added `WITH(FORCESEEK)` after the department table.  Running like a champ now.